# Allow an Apache directory listing from a subdirectory of rails "public/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'd like to enable Apache directory listings on a specific subdirectory of my Rails application's "public/" directory.  For the sake of this discussion, let's say it is the "public/listme"

I've set Apache options to enable directory listings, but if I request something like `http://mydomain.com/listme`, I get a 404 error, and if I check the Rails log, I get an error like:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/listme")`

So: is there a way to disable routing for a specific folder within my Rails app and allow Apache's automatic directory listings to kick in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this question is answered in the modrails documentation. See http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

In summary :

Suppose that you have a Rails application in /apps/foo. Suppose that you’ve dropped Wordpress — a blogging application written in PHP — in /apps/foo/public/wordpress. You can then configure Phusion Passenger as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    DocumentRoot /apps/foo/public
    <Directory /apps/foo/public/wordpress>
        PassengerEnabled off
        AllowOverride all      # <-- Makes Wordpress's .htaccess file work.
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```